# Loop a function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is a node.js, Express, and Mongoose project.

I'm trying to push inputs from a form field (the price of fruit) into an array. There are names of fruit in my DB. Each piece of fruit can have many prices. Users enter many different prices of the fruit, as an array, in my form.

```
router.post('/fruit', function(req, res) {
    //Some code to match the name of the fruit entered by user to the name of the fruit in the DB
    if(!existingFruit) {
    //Some code
    }
    if(existingFruit) {
        Fruit.findOneAndUpdate({fruit: req.body.fruit}, {
            $push: { price: req.body.price1 }},
    //Some code which tells the user whether the price they entered was inserted into the DB or not
});
```

Here is the input field in question:

```
<label for="price1">Price</label>
<input type="text" name="price1" id="price1"/>

<label for="price2">Price</label>
<input type="text" name="price2" id="price2"/>
```

As my backend code, and the form fields, stand only the price entered in 'price1' will be inserted into the DB.

So I am wondering... is there a way for me to loop my backend code over and over again for it to retrieve the values entered in the input field 'price2', 'price3', etc...

Comment: Maybe: ..{ price: [req.body.price1, req.body.price2,...]}... ?

Comment: The problem with this is that users can input anywhere from 1 to infinite prices (they have access to a +/- button that lets them add price fields). So the method you suggested wouldn't work in this situation.

Comment: It works for the part where you update the Mongo collection field, as it should be an array. To know how to handle an arbitrary number of values have a look at the Paul amd PRDeving answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to iterate all the fields:

```
let i = 0;
let field;
while (field = form['price' + i++]) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean that I add this to my back-end code? A few issues... the first is that my current version of node doesn't allow for the use of 'let'. The second issue is that I'm not quite sure how I would add your code to mine? What exactly is 'field' supposed to represent? I know, I'm awful at this.

Answer (score 0):

Express body-parser uses the convention for array access in field names for forms.  So if you name your form inputs something like: prices[0], by the time the body gets to your post method it'll be the first element in req.body.prices.

Fwiw you can also do objects, so if you want an array of fruits with names and values you could create form inputs with names like "fruits[0].name" and "fruits[0].prices[0]"

Comment: So changed the names of my price fields to: price[0] and price[1]. But how do I adjust this part of my back-end code to make it work: req.body.price

Comment: It'll be an array now.